# Archive Utility can't open some gzipped text files based on their contents

Tags: finder, catalina, archive-utility

In macOS 10.15.4, Archive Utility is able to open some gzipped ASCII text files but not others, depending on the contents of the text file. For example, this works:

```
% echo "abc e" | gzip > ok.txt.gz; open ok.txt.gz
```

But this fails:

```
% echo "abcde" | gzip > bad.txt.gz; open bad.txt.gz
```

The second example shows an error in Archive Utility: "Unable to expand 'bad.txt.gz' into 'folder'. (Error 79 - Inappropriate file type or format.)"

[image: Error message showing "Unable to expand 'bad.txt.gz' into 'folder'. (Error 79 - Inappropriate file type or format.)"]

I'm trying to figure out:

1. Is this a bug in Archive Utility, or am I somehow misusing the gzip format?
2. Assuming it's a bug, what *is* the bug? Which files are allowed and which aren't?

Why I believe this is specific to Archive Utility on 10.15:

- 10.14 and 10.13 don't seem to have this problem; the files open normally.
- The bytes of the gzip files created on 10.15 seem to match ones created elsewhere, and open normally with `gunzip` on 10.15.

Text file contents that work or don't work:

- Text files without spaces don't work, such as `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`
- Text files with spaces at the end don't work, such as `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "`
- Text files with internal spaces do work, such as `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy z"`
- Text files without spaces but shorter than five characters do work, such as `"abcd"`

What could be going on?

Comment: I've got this problem in macOS 13.1. Breaks on [Wikipedia dump list of page titles in main namespace](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20240301/enwiki-20240301-all-titles-in-ns0.gz)

Answer (score 10):

For anyone still having this issue and cannot update to a more recent OS, I was able to unzip my `.gz` files through in Terminal with:

```
gunzip '/path/to/file.gz'
```

I'm running macOS 10.15.7.

[Source](https://setapp.com/how-to/open-tar-gz-file)

Answer (score 9):

Someone in another forum sleuthed this out. If you run Archive Utility in the terminal, it shows a more complete error message:

```
Error unarchiving Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=79 "Inappropriate file type or format" (Missing type keyword in mtree specification)
```

Turns out Archive Utility on Catalina is misdetecting text files as mtree files, which is a documented way to misconfigure libarchive ([bug 1](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/issues/507); [bug 2](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/issues/1051)).

This means, in addition to Archive Utility on 10.15.4 failing to decompress some simple text files like "hello", it will also do surprising things with text files that match the mtree format. For example, decompressing "hello type=dir" will create a directory that can only be deleted with sudo:

```
% echo "hello type=dir" | gzip > hello.txt.gz; open hello.txt.gz
% ls -l
total 8
d---------  2 jcushman  staff  64 Apr 20 09:36 hello
-rw-r--r--@ 1 jcushman  staff  35 Apr 20 09:36 hello.txt.gz
```

Comment: `chmod 777 hello; rm -r hello` should work as well, as long as you are allowed to write into the current directory (which you are, otherwise the extraction would have failed)

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer mentioned this is a bug. You can use other utilities, e.g., https://theunarchiver.com/ and extract the contents of your gzipped file.

Easiest way is to install unarchiver and associate .gz files with it, and then open your gz file with unarchiver.

Comment: In MacOS Monterey 12.4 the Unarchiver sometimes fails as well. Specifically with .gz files created when dumping a .gz compressed .sql file from phpmyadmin